# STOSB instruction not storing byte when run from a bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, bootloader, real-mode

After making a small bootloader to teach myself assembly language, I noticed that the `stosb` instruction does not seem to be work. I compressed the issue to a minimal example:

```
BITS 16

start:
mov ax, 07C0h       
add ax, 288     
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 4096

mov ax, 07C0h       
mov ds, ax ;setting up stack

mov al, 'j'
mov di, buffer
stosb

mov si, buffer
jmp loops

loops:
mov ah, 0Eh
lodsb
cmp al, 0
je done
int 10h
jmp loops

done:
hlt

buffer times 64 db 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
dw 0xAA55
```

When this bootloader is run it should store the letter `j` into a buffer, and then print that buffer to the display. The output should be:

> j

When run it doesn't seem to print anything. What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where do you setup the ES register?

Comment: Does the ES register have to be initialized/set up for this to work?

Comment: RTM: `stosb` refers to `ES` by default unless you provide a segment override.

Comment: Yes, the STOSB instruction stores data at [ES:DI] by default. See an [instruction set reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/) for information on [STOSB](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_306.html)

Comment: Ok so would i point ES to the buffer then?

Comment: You probably want ES == DS

Comment: You can set it to the same value you are using for DS which is 0x7c0

Comment: This is more understandable in the context of the `movsb` instruction in the same family, which can move data between segments - the simpler instructions follow the same pattern.

Comment: After setting ES to 0x7c0 everything seems to work! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Such as `mov ds, ax; mov es, ax`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Would you like to write an answer to this question so that it can be accepted?

Comment: @user1354557 I think the question has been asked in other forms (although not an exact duplicate) on SO. Anyone who wishes to answer it can be my guest.

Comment: @zerotwo77 You must also set the direction flag (CLD or STD) before string instruction execution!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was given by Michael Petch, Weather Vane, Jim Mischel, and GJ in the comments.  To elaborate:

The `STOSB` instruction implicitly stores data to `[ES:DI]`, whereas the `LODSB` instruction implicitly loads data from `[DS:SI]`.  You use `STOSB` to write to `buffer` and `LODSB` to read from `buffer`.  However, you set the `DS` segment register but not `ES`.  Therefore, you are not storing the `'j'` character to the same location that you are reading from.

The solution is just to set `ES` along with `DS`:

```
mov ax, 07C0h       
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
```

**Note:** You may also want to explicitly clear the [direction flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_flag) before using string instructions (e.g. `LODSB`, `STOSB`) in your code.  You can do this with the `CLD` instruction.  The BIOS would most likely leave the direction flag cleared before handing off to the bootsector (which is why it worked for you without the `CLD`), but to be absolutely sure, you should clear the flag yourself.

Comment: IIRC, it's not safe to assume anything about the direction flag.  In general, code as defensively as possible in a bootloader, because real-world PC BIOSes exist with nearly every bug imaginable.  I haven't written bootloader code myself, but that's what I've read.